# IP forwarding with dual-port machines fails for one machine

Tags: networking, router, ip, iptables

I have the following scenario:

A desktop D1, with ip address 192.168.5.25. Default gateway is 192.168.5.101. D1 is on the 192.168.5.0/24 network (Network N1). On this network I have a dual-port machine M1 with two addresses 192.168.5.101 (network N1) and 192.168.1.205 (network N2).

On network N2 I have three dual-interface machines M2 with IP 192.168.1.91, M3 with IP 192.168.1.92 and M4 with IP 192.168.1.94. They are all dual port machines having their second interfaces having public  IPs.

Default gateway on M1 is M2's IP 192.168.1.91.

I can ping from D1 to M1, M2 and M3 but not from D1 to M4.
I have IP forwarding set on all dual interface machines.

I read that setting IP tables rules on M1 to NAT would help. I think that merely forwarding on M1 should have sufficed. 
I tried to disable all firewall rules on all machines to see if it was an IPTABLES issue.

What do I need to do/set so M4 can be pinged from D1.

Comment: is WAN ping enabled on routers?  try adding a static entry
> arp -s 192.168.x.x   {MAC} 00-aa-00-62-c6-09  .... Adds a static entry.
> arp -a                                    .... Displays the arp table.

Comment: @TonyStewart  I am able to ping to the public IP addresses of M2 and M3 from both D1 and M1. arp -a on M1 show the arp tables for all m/c including M4 (as expected because from M1 I can ping to all) so there is no reason to add a static arp entry on M1.  I cannot figure out why D1 cannot reach M4 while M1 can. I can ping M1, M2 and M3 from D1 but not M4.

Comment: What is unique about M4's setup other than IP?

Comment: @TonyStewart  M1 can ping to M4. Since D1 can  reach M4 only through M1 but is not doing so, should I not be looking deeper into M1 rather than M4? I cannot find anything on M1. Even iptables rules are flushed on M1.

Comment: check masks are not 255.255.255.0 on network IP setup, change to 255.255.0.0 or whatever